# swift package show-dependencies for Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I have a large Xcode project that has many SPM dependencies. I'm getting an error:

> multiple products named 'Swinject' in:
> 'github.com--swinject--swinject', 'github.com-swinject-swinject'

This error indicates that one of the sub-dependency of the project is fetched from a different source. However, the target names are identical, therefore we're getting this conflict.

What I'd like to get is some sort of dependency graph for the whole project, similar to what can be achieved with this command for the individual Swift Package:

> swift package show-dependencies

What would be the approach to debug this problem and how can I trace the whole dependency graph not just for the package, but for the whole project?